# Modernizr & html new feature & style

Tags: css, html, modernizr

i never use Modernizr before. so reading a article and found some css with prefix word

```
.no-cssgradient.how the below style will be applied.

.no-js .glossy,
.no-cssgradients .glossy {
    background: url("glossybutton.png");
}

.cssgradients .glossy {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #555, #333);
}
```

what is the meaning of above style....how does it work?

4) how style will be applied automatically?

```
/* In your CSS: */
.no-audio #music {
   display: none; /* Don't show Audio options */
}
.audio #music button {
   /* Style the Play and Pause buttons nicely */
}

<!-- In your HTML: -->
<div id="music">
   <audio>
      <source src="audio.ogg" />
      <source src="audio.mp3" />
   </audio>
   <button id="play">Play</button>
   <button id="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
```

i got the code snippet from a site. what is the use of class name like .no-cssgradients or .no-audio how these style will be applied ?

please explain me in details with example. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features
>   in the user’s browser.

- From http://modernizr.com/

It basically detects what **features** your current browser supports, or what it doesn't support, and then you can use those `class` names to style the page accordingly.

For example - if you browser supports HTML5 and the audio tag, you can display it. If the browser doesn't support the audio tag, you can use `.no-audio` - and hide the player, or provide a fallback option for older browsers.

If you debug the Modernizr site with `Firebug` or an equivalent debugger, you can see the it will automatically add classes to the `HTML` tag.

So you might get something like the following added to the `html` tag, as `classes`:

```
js no-touch postmessage history multiplebgs boxshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns
```

So you know the browser supports those features.

It can also be useful if you want to style the site differently if the user has `Javascript` turned off.